# Inheritable static methods in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, node.js

I have the following structure:

First file:

```
Base = function() {
};

Base.something = function() {
  return "bla";
};

if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && "exports" in module) {
  module.exports = Base;
}
```

Second file:

```
var
  util = require('util'),
  Base = require('./base.js');

FooBar = function() {
};
util.inherits(FooBar, Base);
```

But `FooBar.something` is undefined. How can I inherit static methods in node.js?

Comment: Dear downvoter, would you be so kind to explain your vote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

util.inherits operates on the **prototype** of a constructor function.

You need to use a simple *mixin*, commonly referred to as **extend**. It basically just copies all the properties of one (or many) objects into a "destination" object. (in this case, your constructor function)

If you're using [underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/), you can use `_.extend(FooBar, Base);`

Comment: sweet, than just use `_.extend(FooBar, Base);`

Answer (score 0):

I've found an another solution which is better, because I would use only one library to achieve the same functionality.

This library is the [oop](http://search.npmjs.org/#/oop) by Felix Geisendörfer, he also wrote a tutorial at [nodeguide.com](http://nodeguide.com/object_oriented_programming.html) but it's outdated a bit. But here is a working example for the same problem:

```
var
  oop = require('oop'),

  Base = require('./base.js');

FooBar = function() {
  oop.mixin(this, Base);
};
oop.extend(FooBar, Base);
```

Answer (score 0):

To export static functions in Base, add:

`module.exports = Base;`

inside Base.js.